# How do I cut-and-paste an email, so that paste will be in pure text (stripping all html)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, copy-paste, sharepoint, plaintext

I need to be able to select and copy and email, then paste it into a textbox (Sharepoint multi-line extended field).  It messes things up when you do this directly since emails have a ton of html in them.  How do I copy and then paste the text only?

Comment: Is there a "paste as plain text" option in Sharepoint?

Comment: @ChrisF, I haven't found it yet, but it looks like my real problem may be deeper.

Comment: is there no Paste Special in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do is paste the text into notepad then copy it again before pasting it elsewhere. That should also remove any font styles and colors applied to the text.

Comment: This is the poor man's solution but it WORKS.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you can use Notepad as a middleman for the text, or if you run Windows and you need to do this a lot, it may be easier to download a program called [PureText](http://stevemiller.net/puretext/) that does the same thing.

There are nearly a million other of these scripts, but PureText seems to be the most configurable and GUI-hugging.