# Recommendations for utility to paste plain text?

Tags: windows, cut-and-paste

In order to paste unformatted text, I need to paste into notepad, then cut, then paste in my original target app.

I came here looking for a way to avoid this and found [How do I cut-and-paste an email, so that paste will be in pure text (stripping all html)](https://superuser.com/questions/178067/how-do-i-cut-and-paste-an-email-so-that-paste-will-be-in-pure-text-stripping-al), but the accepted answer said to do my notepad trick.

This is ridiculous.  I'm sick of the cut & paste notepad shuffle.

Are there any utilities which will do this for me?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to paste as plain text by default, but have an easy way to paste with the format on those rare occasions when I'd like to.

Answer (score 11):

You might want to try [Puretext](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/). It runs in the background and lets you set a Hot-Key to paste plain text. It runs on Windows NT/2K/XP/2003/Vista/7.

From their website:

> PureText only removes rich formatting
>   from text.  This includes the font
>   face, font style (bold, italics,
>   etc.), font color, paragraph styles
>   (left/right/center aligned), margins,
>   character spacing, bullets, subscript,
>   superscript, tables, charts, pictures,
>   embedded objects, etc.  However, it
>   does not modify the actual text.  It
>   will not remove or fix new-lines,
>   carriage returns, tabs, or other
>   white-space.  It will not fix
>   word-wrap or clean up your paragraphs.
>   If you copy the source code of a web
>   page to the clipboard, it is not going
>   to remove all the HTML tags.  If you
>   copy text from an actual web page (not
>   the source of the page), it will
>   remove the formatting.
>
> **PureText is basically equivalent to opening Notepad, doing a PASTE,
>   followed by a SELECT-ALL, and then a
>   COPY.  The benefit of PureText is
>   performing all these actions with a
>   single Hot-Key and having the result
>   pasted into the current window
>   automatically.**

Screenshot of the options panel:

[image: PureText Options screen shot]

Comment: +1. Puretext is utterly brilliant. Small, neat, easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

[@scottgal](http://twitter.com/scottgal/status/25309464622) answered my question on Twitter.  I thought I'd pass it along for him.

[ClipboardFusion](http://www.clipboardfusion.com/)

Comment: For Windows 8 users who had gotten used to using PureText, this is now the best option IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you pasting your text into?

Word, for example has a "Paste Special..." option that allows you to paste unformatted text:

[image: Paste Special options]

Comment: This would only work for word...

Comment: Yeah, I've used that, but I can't do that with Outlook ... even though I believe Outlook uses the Word editor.

Comment: @John - for Outlook you could always compose your e-mails as plain text ;)

Comment: @Blood - I know, which is why I qualified my answer.

Comment: It works in Excel too. And there's a keyboard shortcut: Alt-Control-V.

Comment: @ChrisF - I could compose my emails in plain text, but sometimes you need to paste in images as well, and my current corporate signature requires formatting.  And besides, there are other places other than word where I want to paste as plain text (although I can't think of an example now).  ... but thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to write a PowerShell script to do what you want. See [Manipulating the clipboard with PowerShell](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/17/manipulating-the-clipboard-with-powershell/).

Comment: Not the most easy/convenient solution don't you think?