# copy and paste plain (unformatted) text

Tags: copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I cut-and-paste an email, so that paste will be in pure text (stripping all html)](https://superuser.com/questions/178067/how-do-i-cut-and-paste-an-email-so-that-paste-will-be-in-pure-text-stripping-a)
>   [Recommendations for utility to paste plain text?](https://superuser.com/questions/191917/recommendations-for-utility-to-paste-plain-text)

one of my pet peeves is different formatted texts.  Is there an easy way in windows, firefox, or chrome to copy and paste unformatted text.  My current strategy is to leave an instance of gvim open and us it as an intermediary, but it'd be nice if there were an easier way.

Comment: Notepad.exe? :)

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cekbgkmeapobkbadclnkjfjdbpbcaobd

Comment: Duplicate Q: http://superuser.com/q/191917/52492

Answer (score 2):

In some circumstances, paste-special can help. One of the choices (In Win7 at least) is "Unformatted text".